# Chosen plugin: Multiple select menu prompt not showing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My [Chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) select menu is present but it still says "Select Some Option" when I want it to prompt to say "Select at least one category or create it".

```
<%= f.select :category_ids, Category.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]}, {:prompt => "Select at least one category...."}, { :multiple => true, :class => "category-select" } %>
```

The prompt is in the list and not when it being directly viewed like a placeholder. How can I get it this way?

**UPDATE**

When I use `prompt` it actually places it in the drop down and can be selected as a category so that's wrong right there.

Comment: It says to change the default text in Plugin's js file. So may be if you change in the js file it might go away.

Comment: @uDay all of my select menus are different. I wouldn't want to set the js file I don't think?

Comment: @uDay oh ok I had to change `data-placeholder` to `placeholder`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Cool place your answer & tick it as answer. It might be helpful to others. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears for rails you have to change the 2 lines `getAttribute("data-placeholder")?` to `placeholder` instead so, simply change the two lines:

```
return this.form_field.getAttribute("placeholder")?this.default_text=this.form_field.getAttribute("placeholder"):this.is_multiple?this.default_text=this.options.placeholder_text_multiple||this.options.placeholder_text||"Select Some Options":this.default_text=this.options.placeholder_text_single||this.options.placeholder_text||"Select an Option",this.results_none_found=this.form_field.getAttribute("data-no_results_text")||this.options.no_results_text||"No results match"
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this as a simpler solution for adding a placeholder for `chosen` multiselect dropdown

```
= f.select :category_ids, Category.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] },
class: "chosen-select", multiple: true, data: { placeholder: "Categories" }
```